# Unable to filter datasheet form after inserting value in ms access

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010

I am using a datahseet subform in my main form for the realtime view of entries added in the table via the main form. This subform filters data on load event and checks with users windows username and compares it with data, it should only show data of respective owner. That means it willl filter the name field and shows only the entries made by the respective user(to unable users to edit each other's entries). It works well with the below code which I used in this datasheet form's vba :

```
 Option Compare Database
 Option Explicit

 Dim GetUserName As String
 Dim GetEmpID As String
 Dim RecCount As String

 Public Sub GetValues()
  Dim obj1 As Object

  Set obj1 = CreateObject("WScript.Network")
  GetUserName = DLookup("[BAFUser]", "BAF_User", "[BRID] = '" & obj1.UserName & "'")
  RecCount = DCount("[ID]", "Mau_con", "[AdvisorName] = '" & GetUserName & "'")
  Set obj1 = Nothing
 End Sub

Private Sub Form_AfterInsert()
    Call Form_Load
End Sub

Private Sub Form_Load()
    Call GetValues
    If RecCount > 0 Then
     Dim strOpen As String
     strOpen = "[AdvisorName] = '" & GetUserName & "'"
     Me.Filter = strOpen
     Me.FilterOn = True
     Me.Recordset.MoveLast
    End If
End Sub
```

It filters the data on load but problems arises when a new user comes and login, then it will skip the if loop and will work normally, I tried to requery the form after making first entry by the new user & I also tried to call form_load in after insert event but both did not work.

But it filters the data once we close it and reopen it.
What is the best way to overcome this ?
Please ask if any other information needed.
Thanks in Advance.

Comment: You want to say more than one user are accessing file simultaneously ?

Comment: yes all of them are using same file, I did not split it because business is not allowing us to have 15 different files in the shared folder.

Comment: You can share only database and can put front end at every user's end.